# Router re-renders current component, instead of rendering component matched to desired path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In the code below, instead of rendering the "CourseDetail" component on the button click of "Access Code" (in CourseItem), it re-renders the CourseList. I figured this was because I forgot "exact" in it's Route component, however it's there and should be working ok. I was reading a bit about react history, although from everything else I've read, I should be able to do this without history. Any help is appreciated!

App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const courses = ["COMP206", "COMP273"];
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <TopNav />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/research" component={Research} />
            <Route path="/publications" component={Publications} />
            <Route path="/halloffame" component={HallOfFame} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route
              path="/student/courses"
              exact
              render={(props) => <CourseList {...props} courses={courses} />}
            />
            <Route path="/student/courses/:course" component={CourseDetail} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CourseList.js:

```
class CourseList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { courses } = this.props;
    const renderedList = courses.map((course, i) => {
      return <CourseItem key={i} course={course} />;
    });
    return (
      <div className="course-list">
        <CardDeck>{renderedList}</CardDeck>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CourseItem.js:

```
class CourseItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { course } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{course}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
              bulk of the card's content.
            </Card.Text>
            <Button variant="primary">
              <Link to={`/student/courses/${course}`}> Access Course</Link>
            </Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CourseDetail

```
class CourseDetail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("rendered course detail");

    return <div>Course Detail</div>;
  }
}

export default CourseDetail;
``
```

Comment: Any success with creating a reproducible codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this:

`<Route path="/student/courses/:course" component={CourseDetail} />`

to be: `<Route exact path="/student/courses/:course" component={CourseDetail} />`

`exact` key word is different.

at the moment your code is seeing this `/student/courses/` and rendering that before it has a chance to get to the final route

Comment: I have, and I've played around with exact, however it still re-renders CourseList instead of rendering child component

Comment: what route are your visiting when it re-renders?

Comment: I get the proper route i.e. /student/courses/SOMECOURSE, but it re-renders the CourseList before anything, and since there are no props, I get an error as the courses array is undefined and I am trying to map.

Comment: That would go away if it just wouldn't re-render CourseList...

Comment: I think put that route above the other route

Comment: yep just added it

Comment: I don't see it @turkr

Comment: sorry should be there now

Comment: so when you go to that route `/student/courses/123` what exactly do you see happening? it doesn't display `Course Detail`? does it do the console log?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment,

Change your order of routes declaration with exact keyword in courseDetail component,

```
       <Route
          path="/student/courses"
          exact
          render={(props) => <CourseList {...props} courses={courses} />}
        />
        <Route path="/student/courses/:course" component={CourseDetail} />
      </Switch>
```

to

```
        <Route exact path="/student/courses/:course" component={CourseDetail} />
        <Route
          path="/student/courses"
          exact
          render={(props) => <CourseList {...props} courses={courses} />}
        />

      </Switch>
```

It will work. Cheers!!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please try this. Hope it will solve the issue.

Comment: same thing unfortunately

Comment: When you click the Link, does the courseId appears in URL for a while or it doesn't even renders that route in URL bar?

Comment: it renders the courseID exactly how it should in the URL (appears there and stays there). However I am directed to an error page as it re-renders CourseList (without props), and attempts to map an undefined array.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I've updated the answer I think the order of routes declaration is the problem but now I doubt and asked the same question that if URL is changing when he clicks on the Link or not.

Comment: @turkr Could you create a sandbox for the same?

Comment: Sure please share the link

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a Link inside CourseItem component but it doesn't receive Router props so the navigation doesn't work properly

You can wrap your courseItem component with `withRouter` HOC and it should work

```
class CourseItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { course } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{course}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
              bulk of the card's content.
            </Card.Text>
            <Button variant="primary">
              <Link to={`/student/courses/${course}`}> Access Course</Link>
            </Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(CourseItem);
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not change anything

Comment: does the url change? Also can you add a log in courseList render method to see if it actually re-renders